# How to add additional agents to mesosphere dc/os cluster?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

We have Mesosphere DC/OS version 1.7 running on 6 vmware vm's with rhel7 and we would now like to add more agents.  We were able to increase from our initial 2 agents(vms) to 6 agents(vms) by running dcos_generate_confg.sh --uninstall from the boot node. We then added the new ip addresses to the agent list in genconf/config.yaml and ran --genconf, --preflight, --deploy, --postflight.  This worked however the --uninstall blew away our existing public agent, which we had to go back in and re-install.

Is there another way to add agents without running the --uninstall? Very nervous about what that's doing under the hood.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For my part, I also had trouble understanding how to add a node to a cluster, then I found this link that allowed me to do this:

[The Mesosphere guide to getting started with DC/OS: Part 2](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2016/04/26/mesosphere-guide-getting-started-dcos-part-2/)

Go to the "Adding an internet-facing HAproxy load balancer" chapter.

To summarize what I did and which worked:

- BootStrap Node:

  ```
  sudo vi ~/genconf/config.yaml ## add node slave IP

  sudo ./dcos_generate_config.sh --install-prereqs

  sudo ./dcos_generate_config.sh --preflight
  ```

### You can ignore errors from the existing agents and masters—DC/OS is just telling you it’s already installed, and you probably don’t want to clobber that installation in-place.

`sudo scp -r -i genconf/ssh_key genconf/serve $NEW_NODE_IP:~` ## Copy to the node

- New node:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /opt/dcos_install_tmp

  sudo cp -r serve/* /opt/dcos_install_tmp/

  cd /opt/dcos_install_tmp/
  chmod +x dcos_install.sh

  Agent Private

       sudo ./dcos_install.sh slave

  Agent Public

       sudo ./dcos_install.sh slave_public
  ```
- BootStrap node:

  ```
  sudo ./dcos_generate_config.sh --postflight
  ```

I hope that this can help you!

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, that worked great, just what we needed!  A couple of notes .. on the `cp server/* /opt/dcos_install_tmp/` step, I had to use `cp -r `, there are a couple of required sub directories that were not picked up. Also,  had to `chmod +x dcos_install.sh` and fetch_packages.sh.  Just nits.  The command above makes a public node.  To make a private one use: `sudo ./dcos_install.sh slave`.  To make a master node use: `sudo ./dcos_install.sh master`.  We'll be trying that next. Thanks again.